About cantor space
Let $\omega= \{0,1,2,...\} $
A family  $\mathcal I \subset \mathcal P (\omega)$ is called an ideal on $\omega$ whenever for all $A,B \subset \omega $,
$1)\text{ }\emptyset \in \mathcal I\text{ and } \omega \notin \mathcal I $
$2)\text{ If } A,B \in \mathcal I \Rightarrow A \cup B \in \mathcal I $
$3)\text{ If } A \subset B \text{ and } B\in \mathcal I \Rightarrow A \in \mathcal I $
I read from [I. Farah, Analytic Quotients. Theory of Lifting for Quotients over Analytic Ideals on
Integers, Mem. Amer. Math. Soc., $148 (2000)$]
From page $7$ below:

By identifying sets of integers with their characteristic functions, we equip $\mathcal P(\mathbb N)$ with the Cantor-space topology and therefore we can assign the topological complexity to the ideals of sets of integels. In particular, an ideal I is analytic if it is a continuous image of a $G_\delta$ subset of the Cantor space.

I have three questions here:
$1)$ What is the cantor space? I researched that and I find the cantor space that is the set of functions from $\omega $ to $\{0,1\} $ But I can't find what is the metric or topology here. I have to know that because they mentioned sets like $G_\delta , F_{\sigma \delta} $ in the book so I have to know which sets will be open sets. Also, the book is talking about $ F_{\sigma \delta}$ ideals that are the ideals that could be written such a countable intersection of countable union of closed sets.
$2)$ In many books I read the same sentence about considering the subsets of $\omega$ as elements in cantor space ($2^\omega$) because there is a bijection between these two space(By using the characteristic functions) I already have known that but I can't understand why do we use that here? It seems that holding with subsets is easily than holding with these functions!
$3)$ Is there an another definition of analytic ideals? Some book mentions the analytic ideal without any explation. I thought that it has an easily definition that the definition above. It seems so difficult to see if an ideal is an analytic ideal or not by using that definition.

Cantor space is ${0, 1} ^\omega$ with the product topology.

@MatthewTowers Is there any referanses can I read to understand this? I tried to read from Wikipedia about product topology but I couldn't understand

The product topology is covered in any book on topology. I suggest Munkres Topology.

as I understand the topology on cantor space is like the caresain product so an open set in cantor space is a set in the form $\prod_{i \in \omega} U_i$ when $ U_i$ is an open set on ${0,1}$ !! But what the open sets will be here?

First, ${0,1}$ is given the discrete topology. Second, check the definition of the product topology. The products $\prod_{i\in\omega}U_i$ should have all but finitely many $U_i$ equal to the whole space ${0,1}$. Third, an equivalent way to define  this product topology is by a (rather natural) metric: The distance between two distinct subsets $X$ and $Y$ of $\omega$ is $2^{-n}$, where $n$ is the first element of the symmetric difference $X\triangle Y$. Intuitively, the longer (in $\omega$) two sets coincide, the closer they are.

@AndreasBlass since in discret metric all subsets are open then any set in cantor space is in the form $\prod_{i \in \omega} G_i$ and all $G_i \subset {0,1}$ is an open set so every set in cantor space is open. But this doesn't make any sense to speak about $G_\delta$ sets. I can't understand this :(

First, not every subset of Cantor space is of the form $\prod_{i\in\omega}G_i$,  but every subset of Cantor space is  the union of sets of this product form. Second, as I said before, check  the definition of the product topology. Not all sets of the form $\prod_{i\in\omega}G_i$ are open.
